# snowflake error "SQL compilation error: Empty SQL statement."

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

ALTER VIEW "test_RAWDATA" RENAME TO "TBD_test_RAWDATA";

I am getting following error:
SQL compilation error: Empty SQL statement.

I have tried with new sheet as well but it is giving this error everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure you run correctly the SQL statement? I just did a quick test with something like this: **create view "test_RAWDATA" as SELECT * FROM A;
ALTER VIEW "test_RAWDATA" RENAME TO "TBD_test_RAWDATA";** and it worked fine. I think the issue is caused by the way you run the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when you execute certain SQL statements in the GUI along with some comments in the same line of the code. For example:

```sql
USE ROLE SYSADMIN;
USE "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC";
CREATE TABLE t1 (id integer);
CREATE VIEW test_view as SELECT * FROM t1;

## View TEST_VIEW successfully created.
```

Now we can ALTER the view:

```sql
ALTER VIEW test_view RENAME TO test_view2;

##  Statement executed successfully.
```

but, if we add a comment:

```sql
ALTER VIEW test_view2 RENAME TO test_view3 ;  /* A comment */

## SQL compilation error: Empty SQL statement.
```

Comment: This no longer occurs in Snowsight, just tested it

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake it still happens in the classic Web UI though

Comment: I will try..thanks so much for swift response

Comment: Snowsight will at some point replace Classic UI - you won't expect any more development on the Classic UI